# SQL / Oracle to Tableau - How to combine to sort based on two fields?

Tags: sql, oracle, tableau-api

I have tables below as follows:

tbl_tasks

```
+---------+-------------+
| Task_ID | Assigned_ID |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |           8 |
|       2 |          12 |
|       3 |          31 |
+---------+-------------+
```

tbl_resources

```
+---------+-----------+
| Task_ID | Source_ID |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         4 |
|       1 |        10 |
|       2 |        42 |
|       4 |         8 |
+---------+-----------+
```

A task is assigned to at least one person (denoted by the "assigned_ID") and then any number of people can be assigned as a source (denoted by "source_ID"). The ID numbers are all linked to names in another table. Though the ID numbers are named differently, they all return to the same table.

Would there be any way for me to combine the two tables based on ID such that I could search based on someone's ID number? For example- if I decide to search on or do a WHERE User_ID = 8, in order to see what Tasks that 8 is involved in, I would get back Task 1 and Task 4.

Right now, by joining all the tables together, I can easily filter on "Assigned" but not "Source" due to all the multiple entries in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select distinct task_id
from ((select task_id, assigned_id as id
       from tbl_tasks
      ) union all
      (select task_id, source_id
       from tbl_resources
      )
     ) ti
where id = ?;
```

Note that this uses `select distinct` in case someone is assigned to the same task in both tables.  If not, remove the `distinct`.

Comment: Works great. What is the "ti" in the second to last line?

Comment: If I remove the "distinct" and the "where" clause, will this give me a full list of task_ids and whoever is assigned to/sourced to them?

Comment: @buttpee . . . Yes, although you will also need to include the `id` on the `select`.  And `ti` is a table alias.